# Why would you use string.toString()?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to understand why you would ever use toString() on a string.

tutorialspoint.com gives this [example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/javascript/string_tostring.htm).

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript String toString() Method</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var str = "Apples are round, and Apples are Juicy.";
      document.write(str.toString( ));
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Why not just use

```
document.write(str);
```

Comment: it's just an example.... actually there is nothing to do with `toString()`.... Also there is description about the return value ___Returns a string representing the specified object.___ . Also I would always prefer __[MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)__

Comment: poorly docs, take a look to a [real doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString)

Comment: They only want to explain toString method of object, which string is object

Comment: if you didn't know for sure it was a string, toString() will turn it into one...

Comment: I think this is a good, deep, important question and I thank you for asking it!! I’m very curious too, I was just googling. My guess is something like: especially in weakly typed languages, it may make sense to implement even degenerate and trivial functions to ensure they exist for when you don’t know _a priori_ that it’s gonna be degenerate and trivial, like when you don’t actually know the type of `str`. Which feels “impure” and practical, and so, very javascripty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`toString()` method doesn't make any practical sense when called on a "pure" sring, like `"Apples are round, and Apples are Juicy."`.
It may be useful when you need to get the string representation of some non-string value.

```
// Example:
var x = new String(1000);   // converting number into a String object

console.log(typeof x);             // object
console.log(typeof x.toString());  // string
console.log(x.toString());         // "1000"
```

> The **String** object overrides the **toString()** method of the **Object**
>   object; it does not inherit **Object.prototype.toString()**. For String
>   objects, the **toString()** method returns a string representation of the
>   object and is the same as the **String.prototype.valueOf()** method.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toString

Comment: dynamic typing. I've just come across an issue where a library converts strings to numbers where as the browser doesn't. I use `v.toString()` to make sure that anything that has been unwittingly coerced into a number is coerced back to a string.

Answer (score 4):

`string.toString()` is useful if you are not entirely certain wether you might get a Number or a String, and if you definitely need a string to proceed with other calculations, e.g. String functions like `.includes` or `.split`.

Answer (score 3):

Even if you don't use the `toString` function, it is invoked (implicitly) to get the value that is used for the `document.write()` function.

Comment: I think for the answer to be more helpful, you should describe what `toString` `actually does` (when it is invoked either implicitly or explicitly). Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There's no difference. I think that they used the `toString` function just to emphasize that it exists. Every object in javascript has a `toString` function, because it's defined on `Object`'s prototype, like explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString).

The difference is that the `String` type overrides the original `toString` function, otherwise the result would be "`[object String]`".